# How could i get struct as generic from type?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, struct

Hi i made type array for search type in object, if object has that struct(or component) then delete struct(or component) from object.

This is concept of my code but i got error that "'structure' is a variable but 
is used like a type" from the line

```
if (entityManager.HasComponent<structure>(entity))
```

Below is my script.

```
public struct ECS : IComponentData{}
...


static Type[] componentArray = new Type[] { typeof(ECS), typeof(JECS), typeof(JECS2), typeof(JECS3), typeof(JECS4) };

static void ResetComponent(Entity entity, EntityManager entityManager) {

    foreach (Type structure in componentArray)
    {
        if (entityManager.HasComponent<structure>(entity))
        {
            entityManager.RemoveComponent(entity, structure);
        }
    }

}
```

In my opinion, i need to convert type to generic but i don't know how.

Please figure out my problem.

Comment: You cant use generics like this, they are precompiled. What is `entityManager`, what is `HasComponent`?

Comment: The entityManger is class and the hascomponent is method that check entity(object) has struct component or not and return bool value. All of those come from Unity DOTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Assuming `EntityManager` is [`Unity.Entities.EntityManager`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.entities@0.0/api/Unity.Entities.EntityManager.html))

In this scenario, you should not call the `HasComponent<T>(Entity)` method because you have the component type as a `Type` object, instead of knowing the type at compile time.

There is a [second overload](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.entities@0.0/api/Unity.Entities.EntityManager.html#Unity_Entities_EntityManager_HasComponent_Unity_Entities_Entity_Unity_Entities_ComponentType_) of `HasComponent` though, which you *can* call.

```
 if (entityManager.HasComponent(entity, new ComponentType(structure)))
```

Comment: I understand why that cannot used. Thanks to explain to me and figure out my problem its work for me. :)